# Manually caching Rest without checking headers for ETag and Last-Modified

Tags: java, codenameone

I'm using `Rest` to make a call to a remote server that I have no access to. I want to cache received data permanently for offline use without checking *Last-Modified* or *ETag* in the headers.

I expected `CachingMode.MANUAL` mechanism to check if there's an offline content and if there's none, then go online to fetch the content, but it doesn't.

To circumvent this, I had to first use `Rest` with `CachingMode.OFFLINE` and if that returns 404, then make another call with `CachingMode.SMART`.

Shouldn't there be an option of (let's say `CachingMode.OFFLINE_FIRST`) that checks offline first and if no content then goes online with (`CachingMode.SMART`)?

Below is my current approach:

```
Response<Map> response = Rest.get(url)
        .cacheMode(CachingMode.OFFLINE)
        .queryParam("param", value)
        .jsonContent().onErrorCodeJSON(e -> {
            throw new RuntimeException(createErrorMessage(e));
        }).onError(e -> {
            if (e.getResponseCode() == 0 || e.getConnectionRequest().getResponseCode() == 404) {
                is404 = true;
                return;
            }

            throw new RuntimeException("Network error. Please check your connection and try again.");
        }).timeout(6000).getAsJsonMap();

if (is404) {
    is404 = false;
    response = Rest.get(url)
            .cacheMode(CachingMode.SMART)
            .queryParam("param", value)
            .jsonContent().onErrorCodeJSON(e -> {
                throw new RuntimeException(createErrorMessage(e));
            }).onError(e -> {
                throw new RuntimeException("Network error. Please check your connection and try again.");
            }).timeout(6000).getAsJsonMap();
}
```

Comment: I don't think this caching mode is available yet. But, you have put something in the community that could be very useful and even I had achieve this use-case similarily through code once.
Upvote to that!

Comment: Your assertion: «I want to cache received data permanently for offline use», isn't equivalent to download the received JSON in Storage or FileSystemStorage and using that downloaded file?

Comment: @FrancescoGalgani partially correct, but I don't want to rewrite the entire code for downloading, checking if exist, fetching new content if not, and purging when I need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes sense. Added support for this in this commit: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/fd81d979507fb08ee1d595b94df5973b322766a3